# Different onclicks for different elements when adding new elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project where the user decides how many buttons are there, and then each button triggers a different function.

What I have done is: I have an input that asks "Enter the number of buttons" and a "Submit" button. When the "Submit" button is clicked, the value of variable `n` is set to the user-defined value.

I then have the following code (assuming the user has set `n` to 10):

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var x = document.createElement('div');
        x.id = i;
        x.innerHTML = i;
        x.onclick = function() {alert(i)};
        document.body.appendChild(x);
   }
```

What I want is, that when `div` with id `i` is clicked, the pop-up message says `i`. But what has ended up happening is, that no matter which `div` I click, the pop-up message always says `10`.

Why is this happening? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need to change is the assignment of `i` inside the for-loop. Use `let` to define a locally-scoped variable. Also, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` for simple text. It is recommended to used `const`/`let` rather than `var`.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  const x = document.createElement('div');
  x.id = i;
  x.textContent = i;
  x.onclick = function() { alert(i) };
  document.body.appendChild(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use getAttribute to read the id of the elements. I show you an example:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var x = document.createElement('div');
        x.id = i;
        x.innerHTML = i;
        x.onclick = function(e) {
        let dataId= e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id")
        alert(dataId)
        };
        document.body.appendChild(x);
   }
```

### Explanation:

`getAtrribute()` returns the value of an html attribute as a string, just enter the name of the attribute in braces to get the value. In this case I entered "id" which is the value we want to retrieve.

Also to get the value of the element where you click I use `currentTarget`, to accurately retrieve the value of the div that the iteration creates. If you use `target`, and inside the div you have more elements, this code will generate an error. Therefore, it is important to use `currentTarget` for this application.

Answer (score 1):

By iterating over your NodeList elements, you can take this next approach.
First of all, append all your created divs in your HTML and continue by looping through the elements list by `document.querySelectorAll("div")`

That way you select all elements and then assign an addEventListener to each one of the items. On your `alert` function, print `this.id` and it will return you the number of the id of the element which corresponds to your `i` index.

It would be the same also if you just put the whole addEventListener function inside the other loop.

I just separated both so you can understand it better.

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var x = document.createElement('div');
        x.id = i;
        x.innerHTML = i;         
        document.body.appendChild(x);
   }
   
   
   let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
   
   for(var a= 0; a < divs.length; a++){
     divs[a].addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert(this.id);
     });
   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen because after the initialisationn the function will look for the value of `i` which is always 10 (once it has been initialized)

### EDIT

As explained by **@Mr. Polywhirl** in his better answer, you can use `let` in your for loop to declare your variable locally instead of globally.

---

To solve your problem you can pass an `event` to the function (the click event) and the getting your value.

It can be done with either :

- The value of the content (as you did with `x.innerHTML`)
- Adding an id to the div and getting this id

### Example :

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var x = document.createElement('div');
        x.id = i;
        x.innerHTML = i;
        x.onclick = function(event) {
           alert(event.target.innerHTML) // with the content
           alert(event.target.id) // with the id
        };
        document.body.appendChild(x);
   }
```

---